# Remove white space before each input element - caused by new line characters

Tags: html, css

I've noticed the difference in browser behavior if I write HTML code in these two ways - the first is without line breaking:

```
<div class='sep'>&#9642;</div><input type='radio' id='uplToday' name='upldateRangeSel' value='1'><label for='uplToday'>Today</label>
```

And the second:

```
<div class='sep'>&#9642;</div>
<input type='radio' id='uplToday' name='upldateRangeSel' value='1'>
<label for='uplToday'>Today</label>
```

In case of the second example - I can see white space character added before input element (it is selected below - showing in blue color):
[image]

How can I remove this white space? Write HTML code without line breaking is not a good idea..

Comment: Try to float the elements, i will ignore the whitespaces. Or display: inline; i guess.

Comment: The radio button has margin. Set the margin to zero.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *space* that you see here is a characteristic of all *inline* elements - you can *solve* it in many ways - some of them are:

1. Setting `font-size` of *wrapper* element to zero and then resetting it inside the *wrapper*.
2. Using comments `<!-- -->`

See demo below:

```css
.wrapper_1 > *, .wrapper_2 > * {
  display: inline-block;
}
.wrapper_1 {
  font-size: 0;
}

.wrapper_1 > * {
  font-size: initial;
}
```

```html
Using font-size:
<div class="wrapper_1">
  <div class='sep'>&#9642;</div>
  <input type='radio' id='uplToday' name='upldateRangeSel' value='1'>
  <label for='uplToday'>Today</label>
</div>

Using comments:
<div class="wrapper_2">
  <div class='sep'>&#9642;</div><!--
  --><input type='radio' id='uplToday' name='upldateRangeSel' value='1'><!--
  --><label for='uplToday'>Today</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Hmm.. Quite complicated, I thought it would be much simpler way. I will try it.

Comment: I found ``white-space-collapse`` property, but it is not implemented yet.. It seems that comments ``<!-- -->`` or ``font-size: 0;`` is the only solution..

Answer (score 0):

I have used `display:inline-block` try the below snippet , this is what you need , check with the refference link [How to remove the space between inline-block elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements)

```css
.sep {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class='sep'>&#9642;</div><!--
--><input type='radio' id='uplToday' name='upldateRangeSel' value='1'><!--
--><label for='uplToday'>Today</label>
```